# Json.NET: serializing/deserializing arrays

Tags: .net, arrays, json

I'm using a Json.NET library. What's the most convenient way of serializing/deserializing arrays in JSON via C#? For example, I'm trying to deserialize the following text (reading from file):

```
{
    "Name": "Christina",
    "Gender": "female",
    "Favorite_numbers": [11, 25 ,23]
}
```

I'm reading the text above from file to a variable:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText("input.txt"))
```

And then, when I'm trying to extract an array `[11, 24, 23]` with the

```
int[] num = (int[]) o["Favorite_numbers"]
```

I receive an error.

What am I doing wrong? How do I correctly read an array? How do I correctly read a 2-dim arrays of the following kind `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`?

Answer (score 2):

The `Favorite_numbers` property is going to be of type `JArray` since there is no way for it to infer what type it should be.  The most convenient way of deserializing that object is going to be to define a C# class for it and use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(...)` method(s) to deserialize the JSON to your defined class.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're doing. In your case the easiest way would be to create a [JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base). So you could do the following:

```
public class IntArrayConverter : JsonCreationConverter<int[]>
{

    protected override int[] Create(Type objectType, JArray jArray)
    {
        List<int> tags = new List<int>();

        foreach (var id in jArray)
        {
            tags.Add(id.Value<int>());
        }

        return tags.ToArray();
    }
}

public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of objectType, based properties in the JSON Array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">type of object expected</param>
    /// <param name="jObject">contents of JSON Array that will be deserialized</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JArray jObject);

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray jArray = JArray.Load(reader);

        T target = Create(objectType, jArray);

        return target;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then define your model with your new attribute:

```
public class Person
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IntArrayConverter))]
    public int[] Favorite_numbers { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use it as you normally would:

```
Person result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(@"{
                ""Name"": ""Christina"",
                ""Gender"": ""female"",
                ""Favorite_numbers"": [11, 25 ,23]
            }");
```