# How to deserialize with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I setup Newtonsoft Json.net to deserialize this text into a .NET object?

```
[
    [
        "US\/Hawaii", 
        "GMT-10:00 - Hawaii"
    ], 
    [
        "US\/Alaska", 
        "GMT-09:00 - Alaska"
    ], 
]
```

For bonus points, what is this kind of structure called in Json.  I tried looking for anonymous objects, but didn't have any luck.

Comment: Are you looking for de-serialization into a custom object type, or simply a JSON "DOM"?  The DOM is likely much easier, since it wouldn't require any changes to your JSON schema, whereas "serialization" APIs tend to be pickier.

Comment: DOM would be fine by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON.Net uses `JArray` to allow these to be parsed - see:

- [Deserializing variable Type JSON array using DataContractJsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215479/deserializing-variable-type-json-array-using-datacontractjsonserializer) (the questions is about DataContract - but the answer is about JSON.Net - and is from JSON.Net's author)
- [Json.NET: serializing/deserializing arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799423/json-net-serializing-deserializing-arrays)

Answer (score 6):

This JSON string (or almost, it will be a valid JSON after you fix it and remove the trailing comma, as right now it's invalid) represents an array of arrays of strings. It could be easily deserialized into a `string[][]` using the built into .NET [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        var json = 
@"[
    [
        ""US\/Hawaii"", 
        ""GMT-10:00 - Hawaii""
    ], 
    [
        ""US\/Alaska"", 
        ""GMT-09:00 - Alaska""
    ]
]";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = serializer.Deserialize<string[][]>(json);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            foreach (var element in item)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the exactly same result could be achieved with JSON.NET using the following:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

To see a blog entry detailing how to serialize and deserialize between .NET and JSON, [check this out](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/NET-35-JSON-Serialization-using-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx). I found it really helpful.